# Getting 'spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: Bad Request' when re-inputting the redirect URL

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to follow through with the spotipy authentication flow using the util.prompt_user_for_token() method - my overall goal is just to be able to create a user playlist. When I run my code, I am directed to my redirect URL page where the URL is now appended with a 'code=' segment as expected. When I try and copy this URL back into the field when prompted, I always get 'spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: Bad Request'.

Originally I had my redirect URL set as https://www.google.ca/, but after reading some of the other threads I've fallen back on 'https://example.com/callback/' which was also referenced in the documentation but this didn't fix the issue. I would greatly appreciate any pointers!

```py
def authenticate(username):
    scope = 'playlist-modify-public'
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(
        username=username,
        scope=scope,
        client_id='',
        client_secret='',
        redirect_uri='https://example.com/callback/'
    )

    return token


def createPlaylist(authToken, username):
    if authToken:
        spotifyObject = spotipy.Spotify(authToken)
        spotifyObject.trace = False
        spotifyObject.user_playlist_create(spotifyUsername, 'playlistTestName')
    else:
        print("Can't get token for", username)
    return


authToken = authenticate(spotifyUsername)
createPlaylist(authToken, spotifyUsername)
```

This is the full error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PlaylistGenerator.py", line 31, in <module>
    authToken = authenticate(spotifyUsername)
  File "PlaylistGenerator.py", line 15, in authenticate
    redirect_uri='https://example.com/callback/'
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/util.py", line 86, in prompt_for_user_token
    token_info = sp_oauth.get_access_token(code)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 217, in get_access_token
    raise SpotifyOauthError(response.reason)
spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: Bad Request
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put any id or secret in the function. You will be given an id and a secret when you create an account for spotify apps and you will also determine a redirect url. You will also use these three aside from the username. I assume you have probably solved the problem but I am giving this answer for others. Read the documentation carefully.